# Deploying 2 apps from the same git using CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

We have an app with web and worker nodes - the code for both is in the same git but gets deployed to different autoscaling groups. The problem is that there is only one appspec file, however the deployment scripts (AfterInstall, AppStart, etc.) for the web/worker nodes are different. How would I go about setting my CodeDeploy to deploy both apps and execute different deployment scripts ?

- (Right now we have an appspec file that just invokes chef recipes that execute different actions  based on the role of the node)

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is very old, but I had the same question/issue recently and found an easy way to make it work.

I have added two appspec files on the same git: `appspec-staging.yml`, `appspec-storybook.yml`.

Also added two buildspec files `buildspec-staging.yml`, `buildspec-storybook.yml`(AWS CodeBuild allows specify the buildspec file).

The idea is after the build is done, we will copy and rename the specific appspec-xx.yml file to the final appspec.yml file, so finally, in the stage of CodeDeploy, we will have a proper appspec.yml file to deploy. Below command is for linux environment.

```
   post_build:
    commands:
      - mv appspec-staging.yml appspec.yml
```

Comment: It worked for me! The best answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of environment variables exposed by the agent in your deployment scripts to identify which deployment group is being deployed.
Here's how you can use them https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1PX2XMPLYPULD/Using-CodeDeploy-Environment-Variables

Thanks,
Surya.

Answer (score 1):

Update - according to an Amazon technical support representative it is not possible. 
They recommend having separate gits for different environments (prod,staging,dev,etc.) and different apps. 
Makes it harder to share code, but probably doable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have got around this is to have an appspec.yml.web and an appspec.yml.worker in the root of the project. I then have two jobs in Jenkins; one each that correspond to the worker and the web deployments. In each, it renames the appropriate one to be just appspec.yml and does the bundling to send to codedeploy.