# AWS Codedeploy for different branches

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS code pipeline, how to configure it for different branches?
I have two branches master and dev and need different configurations (appspec.yml)
was not able to find any good documentation related to this.
Could someone help on this?

Comment: Have a build stage which creates correct appspec.yml based on your branch before deployment stage.

Comment: Hey @Marcin, ya seems like that is the only solution
thanks.
Found same solution here also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507946/12912841

Comment: I would use two pipelines.  How can you tell without detailed inspection which has been run thru the pipeline.  We have a pipeline per branch.

Comment: @TimBassett, even I have same use case (master & develop branch) and have created two pipelines, but there can be only one appspec.yml file so was looking how to provide different appspec config for each branch

Comment: and also found the below article related to environment variable at codedeploy level, but didn't get info on how to configure them
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/

Comment: I'm not going to be able to provide you with a "canned solution", but here's some ideas.  I haven't use CodeDeploy, but you can set environment variables in earlier pipeline actions and export them from your buildspec and then ingest them in later actions.  You need to use variable namespace for the action to export it and then you use that namespace in your pipeline later.  Also, we were copying one of two app.configs to a final.app.config during a codebuild and putting it into the artifact that way.  You could do that, have two separate configs and decide which to copy to the artifact.

Comment: @TimBassett thanks for the input, I will check them out

Answer (score 1):

I will like to answer this, as I was in the same situation and mindest. Most people compare the Jenkins strategies and try to apply them in the code pipeline. (Keeping the branch variable)

Understanding the two systems. Code Pipeline wasn't designed to handle such complex configurations. There is a way to do it (but the complexity defeats the purpose of doing it). It requires a way complex understanding of the system, which the devs in the initial phase of exploring the service might not have.

Here is the article explaining how you can create a multi-branch strategy.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/multi-branch-codepipeline-strategy-with-event-driven-architecture/

> I understand it now, but when I was just starting, it was a nightmare.

The easiest approach will be to have two separate buildspec.yml with two code build applications and change the appspec.yml dynamically while exporting artefacts in code build. Code deploy will take care of deployment configurations based on appsepc.yml.

If such reconfigurability is an issue for you, I'll recommend exploring Jenkins & other options.

Comment: Thanks for the link and Ya I am using the 2nd method now to handle different branches.